# Filter Pandas Dataframe by Removing matching email domains from multiple columns

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, filter

I have this dataframe: I want to filter out rows where the domains in column "Email__c" matches the domains from either columns "Internal_Email" or "Alt_Email".
For example, in the first row, the substring/domain "compx" from "doug@compx.com" matches the substring/domain in "ruda@compx.com" and "sales@compx.com" so I want that row to be filtered out.
All the rows in the dataframe below should be filtered out.

```
Company        Email__c      Action      Internal_Email            Alt_Email
CompX     doug@compx.com      View        ruda@compx.com        sales@compx.com
Doit Inc  try@doit.com.au     View        pop@doit.com          info@doit.com
PIA       mbosi@pia.com       Sell        voss@pia.com          info@pia.com
Techy     pat@techy.com.br    Buy       tra@techy.com.br        contat@techy.com.br
Techy     pat@techy.com.br    Buy       tra@techy.com.br        contat@techy.com.br
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
s1 = df.Email__c.str.findall(r'@(\w+).')
s2 = df.Internal_Email.str.findall(r'@(\w+).')
s3 = df.Alt_Email.str.findall(r'@(\w+).')

df[s1.ne(s2) & s1.ne(s3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df.loc[~((df["Email__c"].apply(lambda x: x.split("@")[1]) == df["Internal_Email"].apply(lambda x: x.split("@")[1])) | (df["Email__c"].apply(lambda x: x.split("@")[1]) == df["Alt_Email"].apply(lambda x: x.split("@")[1])))]
```

Comment: The whole string does not have to match, only the domain, or the substring after @.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';'). # i just save your data in csv and read it then
df
```

out:

```
    Company Email__c    Action  Internal_Email  Alt_Email
0   CompX   doug@compx.com  View    ruda@compx.com  sales@compx.com
1   Doit Inc    try@doit.com.au View    pop@doit.com    info@doit.com
2   PIA mbosi@pia.com   Sell    voss@pia1.com   info@pia.com
3   Techy   pat@techy.com.br    Buy tra@techy.com.br    contat@techy1.com.br
4   Techy   pat@techy.com.br    Buy tra@techy.com.br    contat@techy.com.br
```

Processing conditions:

```
df['email_c_domain'] = [x.split('@')[1] for x in df['Email__c']]   # make additional column with only domain
df['filter_out_1'] = [x.split('@')[1] for x in df['Internal_Email']] # make additional column with only domain 
df['filter_out_2'] = [x.split('@')[1] for x in df['Alt_Email']] # make additional column with only domain 
df['match_1'] = (df['email_c_domain'] == (df['filter_out_1'])) # match domains from email_c to Internal_email
df['match_2'] = (df['email_c_domain'] == (df['filter_out_2']))  # match domains from email_c to Alt_email
df['filtered_out'] = df['match_1'] | df['match_2'] # chose if one of match will true
```

Now df looks like this:

```
    Company Email__c    Action  Internal_Email  Alt_Email   email_c_domain  filter_out_1    filter_out_2    match_1 match_2 filtered_out
0   CompX   doug@compx.com  View    ruda@compx.com  sales@compx.com compx.com   compx.com   compx.com   True    True    True
1   Doit Inc    try@doit.com.au View    pop@doit.com    info@doit.com   doit.com.au doit.com    doit.com    False   False   False
2   PIA mbosi@pia.com   Sell    voss@pia1.com   info@pia.com    pia.com pia1.com    pia.com False   True    True
3   Techy   pat@techy.com.br    Buy tra@techy.com.br    contat@techy1.com.br    techy.com.br    techy.com.br    techy1.com.br   True    False   True
4   Techy   pat@techy.com.br    Buy tra@techy.com.br    contat@techy.com.br techy.com.br    techy.com.br    techy.com.br    True    True    True
```

And now lets filtered it:

```
df[df['filtered_out'] == False]
```

Output is:

```
     Company        Email__c    Action  Internal_Email  Alt_Email   email_c_domain  filter_out_1    filter_out_2    match_1 match_2 filtered_out
1   Doit Inc    try@doit.com.au View    pop@doit.com    info@doit.com   doit.com.au doit.com    doit.com    False   False   False
```